# Setting Selected Values Using Ajax on Select2

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

```
var $Multi = $('#my_multi_select').select2();

$Multi.val(["25","1010"]).trigger("change");  <--- works
```

This works as expected but when I use AJAX to fetch and return ["25","1010"] and attempt to use that in the call, it does not do anything, as in nothing is selected from the list of values.  No errors, just doesn't seem to do anything.

```
var test = '["25","1010"]'; <-- simulate what comes back from AJAX call

$Multi.val(test).trigger("change");  <----- does nothing (nothing selected)
```

It must be something stupid simple but any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var test='["25","1010"]'` to `var test=["25","1010"]`.It is an array,not a string.

Comment: Doh!  Yes, I was making the string look like the array instead of making it an array!